# Symmetry issue 2023

Tags: sculpting

been working on learning blender and making a model. Unfortunately after merging objects and remeshing them it changes the symmetry/origin and I tried using some methods I saw to fix it but it does not work. The origin to geometry doesnt work, origin to 3d pointer doesnt work, tried shift + c method. Nothing works unless I go abck to the point of before merging objects but I want them to be merged. When I try the mirror modifier it makes the model look like this

[image]

how do I fix this ??

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: if you enable the X symmetry but the object is not symmetrical, the sculpt won't act the same on the 2 parts, you need your object to be symmetrical first

Comment: the thing is I used symmatrey to sculpt both objects seperately before merging so I am not sure how to check that

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be because you forgot to turn on *Symmetry* during engraving or your coordinates are not correct, if the latter is the case please use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> to adjust or solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: that fixed the issue, to which I did apply to all transformations and it worked !

Comment: @moxartz Hello and welcome. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @Kiara Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.